# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Ionic, AngularJS, Spring Boot 1.3

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ionic-framework, cors

I am using Ionic and Spring Boot 1.3. It wasn't until I upgraded to 1.3 that I am getting this problem...

Apparently after updating to Spring Boot 1.3. CorsFilter is being ignored completely. All this deprecation is driving me nuts. So I looked up the NEW way and this is what I got.

```
package app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://192.168.1.66:8101")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600)
                .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type", "Origin", "Authorization", "X-Auth-Token")
                .exposedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

The above piece of code is excuted on the boot of the application. Unlike CorsFilter that is executed every time there is a request. But switching to Spring Boot 1.3, I can no longer get this in the chain filter.

Again, the code is being loaded, I set a break point and addCorsMapping is called every time so the settings are being made. So.... Why am I still getting this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.66:8080/login?username=billyjoe&password=happy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.66:8101' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**EDIT**
Below is my old CorsFilter. It no longer works since I updated to Spring Boot 1.3

```
package app.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

    public CorsFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
                         ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        String clientOrigin = request.getHeader("origin");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", clientOrigin);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET,  DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Auth-Token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I am using a CustomToken Login and for some reason The new Configurations for 1.3 and higher do not set the response with Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using custom Login Authentication. So somewhere in my custom login I had to add the response header.

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.1.66:8080");
```

In older versions of Spring, the CorsFilter is set in the filter so it would set this everytime a call is made. It seems the New Configs only work when properly calling a Controller but since login is handled in the Filters and not a Controller, the response body is never set. It properly authenticates the user `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this. It's working for me:.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Before Updating to 1.3 Spring Boot. I had something like this and it worked perfectly. Since I updated to Spring Boot 1.3, it completely ignores it now. which is why I added the newer setup. I've added my CorsFilter above. Its similar to your except I get the Origin of the IP and set it to the Access Control Allow Origin. In any case, the file is being completely ignored which means no settings are ever being applied. I also would like to add that I am using WebSocket layer which does not allow the astrick value.

Answer (score 1):

In a my open source project I needed of CORS support befor the update to Spring 4.2 I used a filter like this:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

as the answare of Raca. However when I update at spring-boot 1.3.3 I changed the configuration as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableEurekaClient
@RibbonClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "it.valeriovaudi.documentlibrary.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@PropertySource("classpath:restBaseUrl.properties")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) // without this declaration the RestTemplate injection wil be fails becouse spring cloud proxied this class for load balance with netflix ribbon
public class UserDocumentLibraryClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserDocumentLibraryClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurerSupport() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer exceptionHandling() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/exception"));
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

this is taken from the main configuration of my project and this kind of configuration works well for me even in a complex distributed system with netflix api of Spring cloud.

I hope that this can help you.